# Adicionar class e remover

Tags: jquery

**Problema**

Quero fazer com que ele adicione o atributo `active` em `suite-internal-item` e remova nos que tem, porém não está funcionando.

**jQuery**

```
$('.suite-internal-link').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.suite-internal-item').each(function(e){
        $('.suite-internal-item').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass('active')
    })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="suite-internal-items">
       <li class="suite-internal-item active">
           <img src="assets/images/aloha1.jpg" alt="">
       </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha2.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha3.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
</ul>
    <div class="suite-internal-links">
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha3.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Estou querendo fazer com que ele adc o atributo 'active' na class suite-internal-item e remova os active que tem, mais nao esta funcionando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer isso pegando o `index` do elemento clicado e aplicar ao mesmo index do elemento da lista usando o método `.eq(índice)` do jQuery:

```js
$('.suite-internal-link').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.suite-internal-item')
    .eq($(this).index())
    .addClass('active')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.suite-internal-item.active{
   background: red;
}

img{
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suite-internal-items">
       <li class="suite-internal-item active">
           <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
       </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
</ul>
 <div class="suite-internal-links">
     <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
     <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
         <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="">
     </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Boa Tio, sabia que tinha uma forma de acessar o index, mas não soube como usar o `.index()` A minha ideia era usar o href para acessar o id da imagem

Comment: Mt bom sam. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode usar o `$(this)` e `.siblings()` para dizer que o item clicado deve adicionar a classe `ativo` ao mesmo tempo que vc remove a classe dos irmão.

Segue o exemplo:

```js
$(".suite-internal-item").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.suite-internal-item.active {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<ul class="suite-internal-items">
    <li class="suite-internal-item active">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
    </li>
    <li class="suite-internal-item">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
    </li>
    <li class="suite-internal-item">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Otimo hugo!! vc poderia me mostrar como eu faria clicando em .suite-internal-link e adc active em .suite-internal-item, dessa mesma forma que você fez, so apenas mudando o alvo para .suite-internal-link.

Comment: Ai fica um pouco complicado, pq como vc vai definir em qual dos 3  .suite-internal-item vc quer add a classe? Vc tem que explicar melhor qual lógica que quer fazer

Comment: Tipo isso que eu estou tentando fazer é um slider com 3 imagens pequenas enbaixo de uma grande ,clicando em 1 das pequenas quero que apareça encima na grande..

Comment: Nesse seria ideial colocar um ID em cada imagem, assim no href do link vc coloca o ID da imagem, tipo assim, `<img id="n1">` e `<a href="n1">` dessa forma os dois dentro o "mesmo" valor vc consegue "linkalos", aqui tem uma resposta que vai de ajudar. Leia o código com atenção, é bem simples de entender! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/284685/porque-o-hover-n%C3%A3o-sobrepoe-a-div/286117#286117

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar dessa forma:

```js
$('.suite-internal-item').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.suite-internal-item').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')   
})
```

```css
.suite-internal-item{
  border:1px solid #f00;
}

.active{
  border:1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suite-internal-items">
       <li class="suite-internal-item active">
           <img src="assets/images/aloha1.jpg" alt="">
       </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha2.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="suite-internal-item">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha3.jpg" alt="">
        </li>
</ul>
    <div class="suite-internal-links">
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha1.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="suite-internal-link">
            <img src="assets/images/aloha3.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Otimo Albertt!! vc poderia me mostrar como eu faria clicando em .suite-internal-link e adc active em .suite-internal-item, dessa mesma forma que você fez, so apenas mudando o alvo para .suite-internal-link.